# How to apply the changes of client settings for one device grouping in sccm?

Tags: active-directory, sccm

I change the restarting the computer parametre in SCCM client settings to false , i don't want to force the restarting , but nothing is changing, i still have a notification with a snooze option and the time remaining before it forces the devices to restart.  why ? what should i do ?

Comment: So did you change that while the countdown was showing or do you mean for future updates triggered after the client settings change you still got the countdown? A already running one would not be affected. For future ones keep in mind that the settings defined in the client setting with the LOWEST priority are the ones that count